# mysql joining and concatinating different tables

Tags: mysql, join, concatenation

I try to write a little voting tool. I have 3 tables: users, locations and votes. votes has 2 foreign keys (user_id and location_id).

Users (example data):

```
+----+----------+
| id | username |
+----+----------+
|  5 | user1    |
|  7 | user2    |
| 11 | user3    |
|  4 | user4    |
| 12 | user5    |
+----+----------+
```

Locations:

```
+----+----------------+
| id | locationname   |
+----+----------------+
|  1 | Pasta          |
|  2 | Burger         |
|  3 | Pizza          |
|  4 | Chinese        |
|  5 | Thai           |
+----+----------------+
```

Votes:

```
+----+---------+-------------+------------+
| id | user_id | location_id | date       |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+
| 30 |       5 |           1 | 2016-06-30 |
| 31 |       5 |           1 | 2016-07-01 |
| 32 |       7 |           1 | 2016-07-01 |
| 38 |      11 |           2 | 2016-07-01 |
| 39 |       4 |           1 | 2016-07-04 |
| 41 |      12 |           3 | 2016-07-04 |
| 44 |       5 |           4 | 2016-07-04 |
| 46 |       7 |           5 | 2016-07-04 |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+
```

The keypair date & user is unique so a user can't vote twice.

I now want to have a list like this for CURDATE():

```
+----------------+----------------+----------------------+
| locationname   | Votes          | Voters               |
+----------------+----------------+----------------------+
| Pasta          | 3              | user1, user2, user x |
| Burger         | 2              | user3, user4         |
| Pizza          | 1              | user5                |
| Chinese        | 1              | user6                |
| Thai           | 0              |                      |
+----------------+----------------+----------------------+
```

How can I solve this? Tried something like that:

```
SELECT locations.locationname AS location, count(*) AS count, GROUP_CONCAT(users.username SEPARATOR ', ') AS Voters
FROM votes
INNER JOIN locations ON votes.location_id=locations.id
    WHERE date = CURDATE()
INNER JOIN users ON users.id=votes.user_id
    WHERE location_id = "1" AND date = CURDATE()
GROUP BY location_id
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Thanks

Comment: group_concat has a length limit that defaults at 1024 characters. if you get any "big" number of votes, it WILL silently truncate the list of voters. And joins are wrong. they do not have `where` clauses. you can only have one `where` in a query, and it doesn't go into the joins.

Comment: ok thanks. any idea how I get to the result?

Comment: So id is redundant. Just sayin'

Comment: I'll take a look. Can you just create the sql fiddle with data so I don't have to spend 10 minutes or more doing all that? Anyone experienced gets bored when that busy work hits them unnecessarily. So they leave.

Comment: Please find the sqldump here: [Dropbox-Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ioscb9f05de2ip/dump.sql?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine showed me how to solve this problem:

```
SELECT l.id AS locationid, l.locationname, count(username) AS count, GROUP_CONCAT(username SEPARATOR ", ") AS users
FROM locations l
LEFT JOIN votes v
  ON v.location_id = l.id AND v.date = CURDATE()
LEFT JOIN users u
  ON v.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY locationname
ORDER BY count DESC;
```